# VideoJS override (or extend) XHR/fetch functionality

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, video.js

I need to play different HLS/DASH streams in my app. All of them are from different domains, hence, CORS restrictions are here.

Some of videos might require cookies (Akamai token protection), others (most of them) might not.

All CORS headers are correct:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

when cookies are not required, and

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <my origin>
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

when cookies are required.

For streams, which require cookies, I can set `withCredentials: true` option in VideoJS, which adds `withCredentials` option to underlying XHR client.

Problem is, when I set this option — it breaks playback of streams, which don't require cookies, because sending request with credentials when they are forbidden by CORS is, well, forbidden.... Option `withCredentials` should be set BEFORE the request, but at this moment I don't know yet, does stream require cookies or not. So I am a bit confused.

One solution, which came to my mind, is override VideoJS XHR behaviour, catch CORS error from first request without `withCredentials` option and make a second request, with `withCredentials` option. A dirty one, but I don't know, what can I do else.

How can I override or modify XHR/fetch behaviour?
I use VideoJS version 7.21.2 now.

Comment: Decided, that backend will send a flag for each stream, for frontend to know, should this stream be requested with cookies or without. This is a solution for the problem, but not actually the answer for the question, so I leave it unanswered yet.